# Apache Camel: log the correaltion id after calling the pollEnrich method

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have the below route where I am processing some mail content in it. For debug purposes, I am trying to set correlation id in the logback.xml like `%X{camel.exchangeId}`.
Therefor I activated the MDC logging `getContext().setUseMDCLogging(true);`.  Aftercalling the pollEnrich() the exchangeId `95C1D8CE0CF95D7-0000000000000001` is not deleted. How can I log/print the CorrelationId (exchangeId) after calling the pollEnrich method in my case?

**route**

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    
    getContext().setUseMDCLogging(true);
    
    from("direct:process_polling_email")
    .log("Hello World")
    .routeId("routeId_123456789")
    .doTry()
        .log("doTry: exchangeProperty.subject - ${exchangeProperty.subject}")
        .pollEnrich().simple("...."
                + "?username={{imap.username}}&"
                + "password={{imap.password}}&"
                +"folderName={{imap.fetch.folder}}&"
                +"copyTo={{imap.tocopy.folder}}&"
                +"searchTerm.subject=${exchangeProperty.subject}&"
                +"fetchSize=1&"
                +"searchTerm.unseen=true&"
                + "closeFolder=false&"
                + "disconnect=false&"
                +"sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true&"
                +"bridgeErrorHandler=true")


    .endDoTry()
    
    .log("After pollEnrich ");
    
    }
```

**logback.xml:**

```
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} %X{camel.exchangeId} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
```

**logs:**

2022-06-03 13:39:00 [Camel (camel-1) thread #6 -  INFO  routeId_123456789 95C1D8CE0CF95D7-0000000000000001 - doTry: exchangeProperty.subject - Hello World
2022-06-03 13:39:01 [Camel (camel-1) thread #6 -  INFO  routeId_123456789  - After pollEnrich

Comment: Did you already try `%X{camel.correlationId}`?

Comment: @TacheDeChoco: I tried it and does not work. With `%X{camel.correlationId}` nothing is being printed.